# PHP SoapClient returns NULL (cakephp)

Tags: php, cakephp, soap-client

So, I have following problem:

I am using plugin CakeSoap for get data from SAP.

If I test with my internal link (in house) it is working, but if I try with external link I am geting following error:

```
"Failed to open stream: Could not connect because the target computer denied the connection." and "I/O warning : failed to load external entity "http://..."
```

Also, if I try to load this link directly from browser it is working.

I have read all threads on StackOverflow and in my options parameter "trace" is setted to "true"

here is the example of my connection

```
private function getDataSAP($SAPcustomerID, $SAPdestinationIDS){
              $soap = new CakeSoap([
                'wsdl' => Configure::read('SAP_WSDL_CUSTOMER'),
                'login' => Configure::read('SAP_USERNAME'),
                'password' => Configure::read('SAP_PASS'),
                'location' => Configure::read('SAP_WS_CUSTOMER'),
              ]);

              //Collect all products from specific user and his destinations
              $all_data = [];
                  foreach($SAPdestinationIDS as $data){
                    $all_data[] = $soap->sendRequest('ZGetCustomerData', [
                      'ZGetCustomerData' => [
                        'ICustomer' => $SAPcustomerID->customer_number,
                          'ItLocation' => [
                            'item' => [
                              'Servloc' => $data->destination_number
                            ]
                          ]
                      ],
                    ]
                  );
                  }

              $all_destinations = [];
              foreach($all_data as $my_containers){
                      $all_destinations[] = json_decode(json_encode($my_containers->EtLocation->item), true);
              }

              return $all_destinations;
            }
```

And there are options from my CakeSoap.php file

```
$options = [
            // 'trace' => Configure::read('debug'),
            'trace' => true,
            'stream_context' => $context,
            'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE
        ];
```

Additional I have tried to make request using SoapUI software and it is working.

So my question is why this link doesnt work in php?

Thank you for helping!

Comment: What part of this error message are you not understanding? "Failed to open stream: **Could not connect because the target computer denied the connection.**"? Figure out why.

Comment: Why it is working with other tools like SoapUI 5.2.1 (software) or with direct link in browser and with php not? this part :)